# Can I run ios app in windows after eject?

Tags: ios, react-native

I develop hybrid mobile application using react-native. I want to run ios app on my Iphone 7 in windows laptop. So I use expo and eject my project. In this point, can i run ios application in windows laptop after eject expo? I need bluetooth module but expo not supported. help me plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need macOS (either on a real Mac or via Hacintosh) and run Xcode there to run your app.